# Error while trying to run project: Unable to start debugging

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, 64-bit, visual-studio-debugging

I get the error below when trying to debug an Any CPU console app. When I switch the Platform target to x86, it works fine. I've tried to repair VS2010 and reinstall VS2010.

Does anybody have a solution except for a complete windows re-install?

Comment: http://bacolan.com/vs-error.png  >>> Page Not Found.. Please update the picture.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It functions now, even though I don't do anything special lately to fix it. Maybe it was a mix of http://www.hagrin.com/326/fixing-components-64-bit-debugger-are-not-registered-error, a couple of Windows Updates, reboots and cups of coffee!

Comment: I get this occasionally and simply restarting visual studio 2010 fixes it :/

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me:

SOLUTION: Had to check "Use Managed Compatibility Mode" in Tools|Options|Debugging|General. Debugger is working now.

From [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2576767/error-while-trying-to-run-project-unable-to-start-program-no-more-data-abailable)

Comment: This should be the correct answer, fixes the problem and is a bit more clear.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error when we changed our domain and I had to create a new user profile. Delete the .suo file of your solution, then open it again.

Answer (score 0):

I try to debug an project from VS2012Professional.
But I have below error.

---

Error while trying to run project: Unable to start program 'D:.....exe'
An error occurred that usually indicates a corrupt installation (code 0x8007007e). If the problem pesists, repair your Visual Studio
installation via 'Add or Remove Programs' in Control Panel.

---

In my case, 
my .NET Framework was corrupted.
So, I restore .NET Framework 4.5.1 ( the latest version in my PC) from "Add/Remove Program"(Windows+R -> appwiz.cpl)

Answer (score 0):

I am also getting the same error as " Error while trying to run project: Unable to start debugging ....."
I am using Visual Studio 2015
if you are also using Visual Studio 2015 
then goto below path and change the authentication settings to allow any user to debug (no Authentication) it's resolved my issue:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Remote Debugger\x64

[image: Screen Shot]

Answer (score 0):

"Use Managed Compatibility Mode" + Run Visual Studio as ADMIN helped me

Answer (score 0):

just go to project settings find debug tab and then uncheck the "Enable the visual studio hosting process". My problem solved by doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to project properties and go to Compile Tab and Check Target CPU If it is **ARM64** then change it **AnyCPU** it works